# директива use strict

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать javascript, узнал про 'use strict'. Написано, что нельзя вернуть назад действия, которые были написаны при use strict. Вопрос может детский, но нельзя просто удалить 'use strict'? То есть ключевое слово function оно и старой и в новой версии такое же. Объясните пожалуйста.Спасибо.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/strict-mode

Comment: Вы воспринимаете «нельзя вернуть назад» слишком глобально :) use strict действует только на время обработки текущего файла (или функции, если use strict написан внутри функции), и таки да, объявленный выше по коду use strict нельзя никак отменить где-нибудь ниже по коду. Но это всё происходит только в рамках текущего выполнения файла: если вы удалите use strict и запустите скрипт ещё раз, то это никак не будет связано с предыдущим запуском, и всё выполнится так, как будто use strict и не существовало никогда.

Comment: спасибо за инфу